# Access to PresentationFramework and WindowsBase internal classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I do not know if is possible to use the internal classes and methods from the assembly PresentationFramework and Windowsbase.
I want to access to the method System.Windows Thickness.IsValid internal method.
By other hand, I need to access to other classes as MS.Internal DoubleUtil class from the assembly WindowsBase.

I have tried, for example to use the following command in the AssemblyInfo but without no successful.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("PresentationFramework, 
PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001
000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c49265
1e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f
25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97
c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thicknessconverter has IsValid.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.thicknessconverter?view=netframework-4.8

You don't say what you want to do with doubleutil.

The code is here though:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Standard/DoubleUtil.cs

You could adapt the bits you need into a new class of your own.

The code for the thickness struct is here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Thickness.cs,109d8135ab5a3074